# Need to process a contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I purchased a theme, and I need to make a processing.php for my contact form. The form that sends the data to the server for processing.

This is the form code:

```
                <div class="form_error text-center">
                    <div class="name_error hide error">Please Enter your name</div>
                    <div class="email_error hide error">Please Enter your Email</div>
                    <div class="email_val_error hide error">Please Enter a Valid Email Address</div>
                    <div class="message_error hide error">Please Enter Your Message</div>
                </div>
                <div class="Sucess"></div>


                <form role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="25" cols="10" placeholder="  Message Texts..."></textarea>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: First, should know , here ask your problem, not for doing your project .:)
Seconds , pleas send your database details for store contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,appreciated. i am asking here as i have no idea how to get the form working. I have been trying diffrent methods for the past 3 days, without any sucess. i do not want to alter the form, i need to use it as it is. all i want is a script that will send my me an email with the details from the contact form. Ihave no idea how to get this working, thats why i posted my form detail in here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both shubham and adi's answers are vulnerable to SMTP header injections, allowing your contact form to be used to send spam. It will happen.

Any POST or GET data passed to the additional_headers parameter needs to be sanitised to prevent abuse.

See the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
- https://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php

Comment: Thanks for your input, appreciated. This has been taken onboard and i will make the the changes to secure my form.

Answer (score 0):

see this example

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['contact_name'])&&isset($_POST['contact_mail'])&&isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_mail = $_POST['contact_mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_mail) && !empty($message)) {
        $to = 'your email@gmail.com'; // this is where you want to send the email
        $subject = 'Contact form Submitted';
        $body = $contact_name."\n".$message;
        $headers = 'From:'.$contact_mail; // email of the sender

            if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                echo 'Thanks for contacting us';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Sorry, an error has been occurred';
            }

    }
    else {
        echo 'All fields are required';
    }
}



?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="contact_name"></input><br><br>
    Email Address:<br>
    <input type="text" name="contact_mail"></input><br><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>


</form>
```

maybe this codes can help you